# How do I use ORDER BY before GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (messages and users)

Messages table has the following fields {message, senderid, receiverid}
Users table has the following fields {userid, name, email}

I want run a query that will enable get just the last messages sent to a particular user.
Here is the query

```
SELECT m.message, u.name, u.email 
from users as u, messages as m 
where m.sender = u.userid 
and m.receiver = '1' 
group by m.sender desc;
```

How ever, this doesn't return the what I want because it selects the first message for every message sent and not the last message. A perfect solution would have been

```
SELECT m.message, u.name, u.email 
from users as u, messages as m 
where m.sender = u.userid 
and m.receiver = '1' 
order by m.sentdate desc 
group by m.sender desc;
```

But I am unable to use ORDER before GROUP BY in order to sort from last to first message and then group by users.

Help PLEASE

Comment: Do you only want the last message to the receiver from every sender?

Comment: MySQL5.x or MySQL8?  The later has a cheaper way to select the last message per user.

Comment: mysql 5.7. I want to get just the last messages sent by every user to a particular user and not just the last messages sent to a user

Comment: Yes @AndyLin That is exactly what I want. For example the receiver's value is "1"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    x.message,
    x.name,
    x.email
FROM (
    SELECT
        m.message,
        u.name,
        u.email 
    FROM users AS u, messages AS m
    WHERE m.sender = u.userid AND m.receiver = '1'
    ORDER BY m.sentdate DESC
) x
GROUP BY sender, email, message;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull the last message only, You can try -

```
SELECT m.message, u.name, u.email 
  FROM users as u
  JOIN messages as m ON m.sender = u.userid
  JOIN (SELECT sender, MAX(sentdate) sentdate
          FROM messages
         GROUP BY sender) m2 ON m.sender = m2.sender
                             AND m.sentdate = m2.sentdate
 WHERE m.receiver = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the last N messages for each user.

```
SELECT * FROM messages M1 WHERE M1.senddate 
   IN 
   (SELECT TOP 4 senddate FROM messages 
      WHERE sender=M1.sender 
      ORDER BY senddate DESC)
   AND receiver = 1;
```

In the subquery, modify the top from 4 to N based on your use case. If you want only the last 1 message for each user, change it to 1

Comment: Didn't work either. I still gave the same result I had. I found another way by filtering the result using PHP and that works for now. Thanks for assisting